# wp_remote_post() and Pem certificates

Tags: wp-remote-post

Is it posible to aunthetificate with wp_remote_post() sending the pem, key and password for the certificate.
I tried

```
$url = 'https://xxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz';
$body='{"transactionParameters":{"currencyCode":"978","amount":"35757","paymentMethod":"CARD"},"transactionKey":{"merchantCountry":"ES"},"version":"1.03"}';
$keyssl=base64_encode( urlencode(  $cert.
        ':'. $key.
        ':'.$pass));

    $fields = array(
    'body'        => $body,
    'headers'     => [
        'Content-Type'=> 'application/json',
        'charset'=>'UTF-8',
        'User-Agent'=>'ECOMM_WEB_SERVICE',
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $keyssl,
    ],
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
     'sslverify' => false,
        
);
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, $fields );
```

and other variations, but couldn't get it to work.
Thanks

Comment: where is `$cert` coming from in your code? I'm not sure what PEM etc have to do with what looks like Basic auth, are you trying to talk to a service that uses a self-signed certificate and you want to know how to securely talk and verify with the given public certificate files? What are you trying to do that requires this? Your question as it's currently written doesn't make much sense as that's not what PEM files are used for

Comment: What we are trying is to send a certificate and the key files and the password to authenticate the connection. they are located in two external files. We had it working in curl as:
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $cer_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $key_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $key_password);
We just want to know if this is possible with wp-remote-post
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no provisions in `wp_remote_post` for those parameters. `wp_remote_post` is a high level abstraction around a deeper level API which itself is another wrapper around the Requests library ( which itself provides an abstraction that handles support for multiple HTTP backends, not all servers have curl, or the same versions of curl ).

If we look at `WP_HTTP::request` we can see the full list of arguments it accepts:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/request/

The most you can do is specify options for the remote servers SSL, e.g. a certificate bundle to accept from the remote end, and the option to skip verification. There are no client side options though, and you can't pass in curl constants/keys as curl isn't the only backend in use.

Requests does provide the `requests.before_request` hook to intercept the options and data at the lowest level before it makes the request, but this looks to be quite involved and probably involves writing a custom transport. It would be easier to use a library such as GuzzleHTTP or curl directly.

It's also highly unlikely that you can specify a HTTP header to do this as what you want to do happens at a layer below raw HTTP in the transport layer.